# Pandas duplicating row if condition met, and assigning value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shift

I have a Pandas dataframe like the one below, where **column A** is a series of string values, and **column B** maintains a running total of the number of times the value in **column A** differs from the value of **column A** in the previous row.

```
A    B       
1    1          
1    1             
1b   2          
1b   2                
1b   2    
1    3
```

Every time there is a change in the value of column A, I would like to duplicate the preceding row and assign it an incremented value of column B. For example, with the input dataframe as above, the output would look like:

```
A    B       
1    1          
1    1   
1    2            
1b   2          
1b   2                
1b   2 
1b   3    
1    3
```

Any thoughts about how to go about this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter last duplicated values by `B`, then shifting only `B` and assign back, remove last row and last join togehter by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with sorting by index:

```
df1 = (df[df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift(-1))]
         .assign(B = lambda x: x.B.shift(-1)).iloc[:-1].astype({'B':int}))

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index(ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    A  B
0   1  1
1   1  1
2   1  2
3  1b  2
4  1b  2
5  1b  2
6  1b  3
7   1  3
```